# jquery serializeArray() or serialize() is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

```
var formSerializeArray = $('QDiv').serializeArray();
```

QDiv contains all the input controls... I have used serializeArray() and serialize() as well... But it is not working... meaning it is returning "null" eventhought the div contains controls.

some one please help me... what am i missing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why is your question tagged with `asp.net-mvc-3`? How does your markup look like?

Comment: My markup will look like a customer feedback form with few questions... the questions will be displayed dynamically based on the user's answer... In between i wanted to persist the values of the input controls on the form (so, i have written a javascript function which will handle the input values). That is why i'm using serializeArray()

Comment: OK, please show this markup in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to take @Maciej's answer into consideration first.

You should also check if your form elements have a *name* attribute or else they won't be included when you trigger **serialize()** or **serializeArray()**.

Source: http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg32998.html

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using some recent jQuery, make sure you’re using "#" with id selectors, ie.:

```
var formSerializeArray = $('#QDiv').serializeArray();
```